# How to combine similar items in aggregations?

Tags: javascript, elasticsearch

I'm trying to create a color filter. The colors being returned are mostly normal but there's a bunch of other off ones. Example, my results show up like this:

```js
{ key: "WHITE", doc_count: 300 }, 
{ key: "OFFWHITE", doc_count: 2 }, 
{ key: "SUPER WHITE", doc_count: 1 }
```

My aggregation looks like:

```js
aggs: {
    Color: {
        terms: {
            field: 'colors.keyword',
            size: 100,
        },
    },
}
```

I want to combine anything that includes 'white' together into one bucket. Same with the other top colors. Is this possible and how?

Answer (score 1):

Another approach to this can be by making use of [filter aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-filter-aggregation.html). The filter here can be the [wildcard query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-wildcard-query.html) matching the color.

The aggregation would look as below:

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "WHITE": {
      "filter": {
        "wildcard": {
          "colors.keyword": "*WHITE*"
        }
      }
    },
    "BLUE": {
      "filter": {
        "wildcard": {
          "colors.keyword": "*BLUE*"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The above will not require any script. But as suggested by Kamal the best approach would be to have a separate field such as `primary_color` and aggregate on that.

Answer (score 0):

I've come up with the below query which uses [Terms Aggregation using Script](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation-script).

Note that I've added only conditions for `WHITE` and `BLUE`. It's a simple *if your string contains a colour as substring, return the appropriate **primary/top colour** which would act as key*.

You may have to figure out the **distinct top colours** you are using and add conditions to the script so as to have what you are looking for.

```
POST <your_index_name>/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "Color": {
      "terms": {
        "script": {
          "source": """
          String st = doc['colors.keyword'].value;
          if(st.toLowerCase().contains("white"))
            return "WHITE";
          else if(st.toLowerCase().contains("blue"))
            return "BLUE";
          """,
          "lang": "painless"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now if you have many such colours, instead of above, a better approach/solution would be, try to re-ingest the document with an additional field (have it as `primary_color`) and that the value of this field would only contain the primary/top colours like `white, blue, green, yellow`.

That way you can aggregate on this new field( `primary_color` making your aggregation query lot more efficient.

Let me know if this helps!

Comment: Totally helpful! Thanks so much, I'm trying it out but running into a bit of a problem. I'm trying to run this script within js so figured I could use back ticks to force the painless script into a string, but not sure if this works properly..    
```js
script: {
          source: `""" 
            String st = doc['stdExteriorColors.keyword'].value;
                  if(st.toLowerCase().contains("white"))
            return "WHITE" 
            else if (st.toLowerCase().contains("blue"))
            return "BLUE";
          """`,
          lang: 'painless', 
```

Comment: You can have like below `var query = "{\n  \"size\": 0,\n  \"aggs\": {\n    \"Color\": {\n      \"terms\": {\n        \"script\": {\n          \"source\": \"\"\"\n          String st = doc[\'colors.keyword\'].value;\n          if(st.toLowerCase().contains(\"white\"))\n            return \"WHITE\";\n          else if(st.toLowerCase().contains(\"blue\"))\n            return \"BLUE\";\n          \"\"\",\n          \"lang\": \"painless\"\n        }\n      }\n    }\n  }\n}"`